# Testing email encoded for Japanese

Tags: email, encoding, internationalization

After figuring out how to encode email that will be read by a Japanese user (encoding for IS0-2022-JP and then base64 encoding), I need to figure out how to test that this actually works. I'm not fluent in Japanese. How does one go about testing that the email reads correctly? The message I'm sending would be written by my program in English, to be read by a Japanese user.

Comment: it sounds like you mean: if i send an English message encoded in iso-2022-jp, how can i be sure it will read correctly?  is that right?  if that is the case you do not need to worry. it will work.  on the other hand, if you mean: if i send a Japanese message will it come out ok on the other end, i recommend putting together a short test text:
日本語は難しいです  (japanese is difficult)
and then pasting that into both the subject and the body.  then sending it to yourself and confirming visually that all the characters are the same. obviously that is far from complete, but should work for a first pass.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a hard time dealing with Japanese characters for test cases, why not test using wide latin? Wide latin is the latin character set formatted to monospaced and with their own code points in ISO-2020 and in unicode. If you get yourself a Japanese IME, you should be able to input them.

Here is some comparisons:

```
Hello World // standard ASCII codepoints
Ｈｅｌｌｏ　Ｗｏｒｌｄ // Japanese wide latin
```

Since you will be able to enter and read everything with ease, this strategy might be good for testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending English, you shouldn't need to worry about encoding. ISO-2022-JP [starts in ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_2022#ISO_2022_character_sets).